CHAMADA DE PROCEDURE ANTES DO TEMPO
Tenho uma procedure principal (DistribuirDadosAeronave) que normaliza dados da tabela planilha_aeronave, chamando outras procedures para inserir ou atualizar registros em tabelas como FABRICANTES_AERONAVES e MODELOS_AERONAVES.
O problema é que a procedure de modelos (Proc_InserirModelosAeronaves) está sendo executada antes de os fabricantes serem corretamente cadastrados. Isso causa erro ao buscar o ID do fabricante para associar ao modelo.
O que preciso:
Como garantir que os dados atualizados em uma subtarefa (como fabricantes) estejam disponíveis imediatamente para a próxima subtarefa (modelos), na mesma execução da procedure principal?
Código da procedure
   --Proc Fabricantes
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_InserirFabricanteAeronave
    @P_Fabricante NVARCHAR(200)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @V_IdFabricante INT;
    DECLARE @V_Count INT;
    
    SET @P_Fabricante = COALESCE(@P_Fabricante, 'NÃO INFORMADO');

    SELECT @V_Count = COUNT(*) FROM FABRICANTES_AERONAVES WHERE FBA_NOME = @P_Fabricante OR CAST(FBA_ID AS VARCHAR) = @P_Fabricante;

    IF @V_Count = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO FABRICANTES_AERONAVES (FBA_NOME) VALUES (@P_Fabricante);
            SELECT @V_IdFabricante = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
        END

    SELECT @V_IdFabricante = FBA_ID FROM FABRICANTES_AERONAVES WHERE FBA_NOME = @P_Fabricante OR CAST(FBA_ID AS VARCHAR) = @P_Fabricante;

    UPDATE planilha_aeronave SET aeronave_fabricante = @V_IdFabricante WHERE aeronave_fabricante = @P_Fabricante;
END
GO


--Proc Inserir modelos Aeronaves
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_InserirModelosAeronaves
    @P_Modelo NVARCHAR(100),
    @P_Assentos INT,
    @P_IdIcao NVARCHAR(200),
    @P_IdPMD INT,
    @P_IdTipoAeronave NVARCHAR(200),
    @P_IdFabricante NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @V_IdModeloAeronave INT;
    DECLARE @V_Count INT;

    SET @P_Modelo = COALESCE(@P_Modelo, 'NÃO INFORMADO');
    SET @P_Assentos = COALESCE(@P_Assentos, 0);

    SELECT 
        @V_Count = COUNT(*) 
    FROM MODELOS_AERONAVES WHERE
        (MDA_MODELO = @P_Modelo OR CAST(MDA_ID AS VARCHAR) = @P_Modelo) AND
        MDA_ASSENTOS = @P_Assentos AND 
        MDA_FBA_ID = @P_IdFabricante AND
        MDA_TPI_ID = @P_IdIcao AND
        MDA_PMD_ID = @P_IdPMD AND
        MDA_TPA_ID = @P_IdTipoAeronave;

    IF @V_Count = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO MODELOS_AERONAVES(MDA_MODELO, MDA_ASSENTOS, MDA_FBA_ID, MDA_TPI_ID, MDA_PMD_ID, MDA_TPA_ID) 
            VALUES (@P_Modelo, @P_Assentos, CAST(@P_IdFabricante AS INT), CAST(@P_IdIcao AS INT), @P_IdPMD, CAST(@P_IdTipoAeronave AS INT));
        END

    SELECT 
        @V_IdModeloAeronave = MDA_ID 
    FROM MODELOS_AERONAVES WHERE
        (MDA_MODELO = @P_Modelo OR CAST(MDA_ID AS VARCHAR) = @P_Modelo) AND
        MDA_ASSENTOS = @P_Assentos AND 
        MDA_FBA_ID = @P_IdFabricante AND
        MDA_TPI_ID = @P_IdIcao AND
        MDA_PMD_ID = @P_IdPMD AND
        MDA_TPA_ID = @P_IdTipoAeronave;

    UPDATE planilha_aeronave SET aeronave_modelo = @V_IdModeloAeronave WHERE aeronave_modelo = @P_Modelo;

END;
GO


--PROCEDURE PARA DISTRUIBIÇÃO
CREATE PROCEDURE DistribuirDadosAeronave
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NomePais NVARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @TipoIcao NVARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE @PMD INT;
    DECLARE @TipoAeronave NVARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE @Fabricante NVARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE @Modelo NVARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @Assento INT;

    DECLARE CURSOR_PLANILHA CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 
        aeronave_pais_fabricante, 
        aeronave_tipo_icao, 
        aeronave_pmd, 
        aeronave_tipo_veiculo,
        aeronave_fabricante,
        aeronave_modelo,
        CASE
            WHEN 
                aeronave_assentos = 'NULL' 
            THEN 
                '0'
        END
    FROM planilha_aeronave;

    OPEN CURSOR_PLANILHA;

    FETCH NEXT FROM 
        CURSOR_PLANILHA 
    INTO 
        @NomePais, 
        @TipoIcao, 
        @PMD, 
        @TipoAeronave,
        @Fabricante,
        @Modelo,
        @Assento;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            --Normalizar paises
            EXEC Proc_InserirPaises @NomePais;

            --Normalizar Tipo Icao
            EXEC Proc_InserirTipoIcao @TipoIcao;

            --Normalizar Peso maximo decolagem /PMD
            EXEC Proc_InserirPMD @PMD;

            --Normalizar Tipo de aeronave
            EXEC Proc_InserirTipoAeronave @TipoAeronave;

            --Normalizar Fabricantes
            EXEC Proc_InserirFabricanteAeronave @Fabricante;

            --Normalizar modelos aeronaves
            EXEC Proc_InserirModelosAeronaves @Modelo, @Assento, @TipoIcao, @PMD, @TipoAeronave, @Fabricante;

            FETCH NEXT FROM 
                CURSOR_PLANILHA 
            INTO 
                @NomePais,
                @TipoIcao, 
                @PMD, 
                @TipoAeronave, 
                @Fabricante,
                @Modelo,
                @Assento;
        END

    CLOSE CURSOR_PLANILHA;

    DEALLOCATE CURSOR_PLANILHA;
END
GO


Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema, explicar como tentou resolver e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.
